# Logic of std::is_base_of in C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, std

While going through some of the C++ concepts I stumbled upon std::is_base_of logic.

Googling around for logic produced the below code, but I am not able to understand it.

Could somebody explain me how it works?

```
template<typename D, typename B>
class IsDerivedFromHelper
{
    class No { };
    class Yes { No no[3]; };

    static Yes Test( B* );
    static No Test( ... );
public:
    enum { Is = sizeof(Test(static_cast<D*>(0))) == sizeof(Yes) };

};


template <class C, class P> 
bool IsDerivedFrom() {
    return IsDerivedFromHelper<C, P>::Is;
}
```

Comment: @KerrekSB Where is the SFINAE above?

Comment: @Barry the linked question is explaining different code.  They are both attempts at `is_base_of`, but the linked one looks like it solves the private inheritance problem, while (as far as I guess) the above one does not (and is simpler as a result).  Neeraj, do you want to know how `is_base_of` can be implemented in-language, or do you want to know how the code you posted works?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Is it? Looks like basic overload resolution to me. `D*` converts implicitly to `B*` iif (ish) `B` is a base of `D`. That overload returns a value of a type `Yes` that's three times the size of a `No`, which you can test for with `sizeof`. All other cases result in invocation of the `...` overload which returns a `No`. And the icing on the cake is that the whole thing's in an unevaluated context so nothing's actually invoked and the entire thing can be used as a compile-time constant.

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, but the logic behind why that `is_base_of` works also explains why this one works too - it's just more complex.

Comment: @Barry, I disagree with the duplicate part. The other question has very different code.

Comment: @Yakk: You're right, there's no substitution failure here. Just plain overload resolution.

Comment: Thanks guys for your immediate response. I am more inclined towards understanding the logic of std::is_base_of in C++11.

Agree above code is not the actual implementation of std::is_base_of. I just found it over internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `B` is a base class of `D`, the call `Test(static_cast<D*>(0))` resolves to `Yes Test(B*)`. Otherwise, it resolves to `No Test(...)`.

If `B` is a base class of `D`, the value of `sizeof(Test(static_cast<D*>(0)))` is `sizeof(Yes)`. Otherwise, it is equal to `sizeof(No)`.

`Yes` and `No` are defined such that `sizeof(Yes)` will never be equal to `sizeof(No)`.

If `B` is a base class of `D`,

```
sizeof(Test(static_cast<D*>(0))) == sizeof(Yes)
```

evaluates to `true`. Otherwise it evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Thanks R Sahu. 
Surely I am missing some basics here. 
What is the role of 0 (expression) which is passed in static_cast operator?

Comment: @Neeraj It is an old-school `nullptr`